# Namespaces for interfaces in typescript definition file

Tags: namespaces, typescript

I am writing a TypeScript definition file (.d.ts) for a JS library that doesn't currently have one.

Other .d.ts file seem to put all the types into the 'global' namespace (if you see what I mean), whereas I am trying do the following:

```
// root valerie object 
//
declare var valerie: Valerie.ValerieStatic;

// additional types for Valerie (all inside this virtual namespace)

declare module Valerie {

    //
    // Static methods on valerie namespace
    //
    interface ValerieStatic {
        // definitions go here.....
```

This means that I don't potentially get my interfaces crossed with others should they exist.

My question is - it seems to work, but is there a possible problem with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is a good approach. If there are some interface types inside the `Valerie` module that you would expect people to be using often, you might consider promoting them to top-level so it's more convenient to reference them.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - I was wondering why others didn't follow this approach which made me concerned I was erring from the true path. :)